# How can I instantiate this very sophisticated generic Class that appears in book Open Data Structures?

Tags: java, generics

I am reading the book [Open Data Structures](https://opendatastructures.org/) by Pat Morin. The author use very sophisticated generic code in java to implement BinaryTree.
The code really confuses me. I even can't figure out how to instantiate the BinaryTree Class.

```java
package ods;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

/**
 * An implementation of binary trees
 * @author morin
 *
 * @param <Node>
 */
public class BinaryTree<Node extends BinaryTree.BTNode<Node>> {
    
    public static class BTNode<Node extends BTNode<Node>> {
        public Node left;
        public Node right;
        public Node parent; 
    }

    
    protected Node sampleNode;
    
    
    protected Node r;

    
    protected Node nil;

    
    public BinaryTree(Node sampleNode, Node nil) {
        this.sampleNode = sampleNode;
        this.nil = nil;
        r = nil;
    }

    
    public BinaryTree(Node sampleNode) {
        this.sampleNode = sampleNode;
    }
    
    
    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
    protected Node newNode() {
        try {
            Node u = (Node)sampleNode.getClass().newInstance();
            u.parent = u.left = u.right = nil;
            return u;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
//some method below

}
```

Comment: i dont quite understand `BTNode<Node extends BTNode<Node>>` though, it looks like BTNode expects a Node type which is inheriting BTNode that expects Node and it seems to point back to itself. Why and how is it working like that?

Answer (score 2):

You have to define a class to represent a node type. It will encompass what you want to store in the tree. For example :

```java
public class StringNode extends BinaryTree.BTNode<StringNode> {
    private final String stringValue;

    public StringNode(String stringValue) {
        this.stringValue = stringValue;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return stringValue;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it to instantiate a tree of that node type :

```java
StringNode firstNode = new StringNode("firstValue");
BinaryTree<StringNode> stringTree = new BinaryTree<StringNode>(firstNode);
```

The Node type parameter is defined as a subclass of `BTNode`, so that one can implement [recursive methods](https://opendatastructures.org/ods-java/6_1_BinaryTree_Basic_Binary.html#SECTION00911000000000000000) with it.
For example, the `size(Node)` method :

```java
int size(Node u) {
    if (u == nil) return 0;
    return 1 + size(u.left) + size(u.right);
}
```

It is not possible to write this without `Node` being  a `BTNode` itself.
Because if it is not, there is no such thing as `u.left` or `u.right`.

Comment: This can work, thanks. I still feel confused with BTNode<Node extends BTNode<Node>> . Is it just a thick that makes the generic type can refer the generic class itself?

Comment: In a way, yes. It ensures that neighbours of the node (left, right, and parent) are also nodes themselves, and not just any other type.

Comment: I updated my answer to explain the intent of this design.

Comment: @nquincampoix why/how does the Java syntax allow that? The Node class wasnt exactly properly mentioned/declared(?) anywhere besides the part where `<Node extends BTNode<Node>>` or `<Node extends BinaryTree.BTNode<Node>>`

Comment: @experimentunit1998X that's because it is not a class, it is a type parameter of the class `BinaryTree`. It just has an unusually long name, so it gets confused with a class.

Comment: So, type parameters does not need to be declared like a class? I can just replace `Node` with any other word ie cat and it should function the same in the above code? I looked up and understand that the `extends BTNode<Node>` part is to make the Node type parameter bounded to instances of BTNode or subclasses

Comment: @experimentunit1998X No, it is not declared as a class, it is just defined along a class declaration. And provided it is not a reserved word of the language, yes, you can name it the way you want (the clearer the better, though). Here's a good read about generics : http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html

Answer (score -1):

For the basic it should be looking like this and normaly it should be abstract and you should create extending classes of this tree. Keep clear that each tree also is a node (of some other tree). Remeber that this is only some base now you could implement more methods like getting some seeking node/load in the tree or get the highest or lowest load and so on.

```
/**
 * An implementation of binary trees
 *
 * @param <V> load type
 * @param <N> node type
 * @author morin
 */
public class BinaryTree<V, N extends BinaryTree<V, N>> {

    protected V load;


    protected N rightNode;


    protected N leftNode;


    public BinaryTree(V load, N rightNode, N leftNode) {
        this.load = load;
        this.rightNode = rightNode;
        this.leftNode = leftNode;
    }

    public BinaryTree(V load) {
        this(load, null, null);
    }

    public V getLoad() {
        return load;
    }

    public void setLoad(V load) {
        this.load = load;
    }

    public N getRightNode() {
        return rightNode;
    }

    public void setRightNode(N rightNode) {
        this.rightNode = rightNode;
    }

    public N getLeftNode() {
        return leftNode;
    }

    public void setLeftNode(N leftNode) {
        this.leftNode = leftNode;
    }
    
    //some more methods
}
```